# Explaining the relative share of the income & substitution effects of a price change

Tags: microeconomics, slutsky-equation

Let's say you have a Cobb-Douglas utility function, U = x^.1*y^.9

This will result in Marshallian demand functions x* = .1I / Px, and y* = .9I / Py.

If you perform a Slutsky decomposition for x* as Px changes; the income effect will be 10% of the total effect.

Can someone help me understand why the effect exactly matches the percent of income spent on the good?

Answer (score 1):

The income effect is given by:
$$
x^\ast \frac{\partial x}{\partial I} = \frac{0.1 I}{P_x} \frac{0.1}{P_x} = 0.1\left(0.1\frac{I}{(P_x)^2}\right).
$$
The Price effect is:
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial P_x} = -0.1 \frac{I}{(P_x)^2}.$$
The first is 10% of the second (in absolute terms).

Another way to see this, is to start from the fact that for the Cobb-Douglass, the expenditure share is constant:
$$
\frac{p x(p,I)}{I} = \alpha.
$$
Taking derivative with respect to $p$ gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{x(p,I) + p \frac{\partial x}{\partial p}}{I} = 0,\\
\to &\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = -\frac{x(p,I)}{p}
\end{align*}
$$
Taking the partial derivative with respect to $I$ gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{p \frac{\partial x(p,I)}{\partial I} I - p x(p,I)}{I^2} = 0,\\
\to &\frac{\partial x(p,I)}{\partial I} = \frac{p x(p,I)}{pI} = \frac{\alpha}{p}
\end{align*}
$$
So the income effect is:
$$
\frac{\partial x(p,I)}{\partial I} x(p,I) = \alpha \frac{x(p,I)}{p}
$$
This is $\alpha$ times the absolute value of the price effect.

Comment: This makes sense, but is there any specific mathematical reason as to why the price effect is *exactly the same* as the share of income spent on the good? Or does it just happen to work that way?

Comment: @Aa Z I added some additional explanation.